# How to automatically add comments to your gettext strings when running xgettext

Tags: php, gettext, xgettext

So I use gettext in my php project to translate strings. However, in som cases, the context of a string is not obvious so I would like to add a comment to the string for the translator. However, it is not clear to me how to do this in a good way.

I would love to do it like this:

```
_("My text string","My comment that describe the string context for my translator")
```

When I code I use:

```
find ./app -iname "*.php" | xargs xgettext -d app/Locale/messages
```

To scan for new strings and then compile the messages.po file.

Is it possible to add comments to text strings like this? Or what is the best practice for adding comments for translators?

Best!
Samuel

I haven't seen any similar solutions yet when googling...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible quite the way you describe, but use e.g. `--add-comments=TRANSLATORS` for `xgettext`, and any comment nearby a `_()` call and beginning with `TRANSLATORS:` will be added to the output. See also [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html#Operation-mode).

Comment: Aha, so if I runt xgettext -add-comments=TRANSLATORS and in my code do something like this _("Home" /* TRANSLATORS: This is the home button.  */)

Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: I have always inserted the comment right before the `_()` call, but possibly it can be within `_()` as well.

Comment: Nah that didn't work actually. As you said, it had to be before to be added to the correct string.

Answer (score 0):

Context-aware functions (`pgettext` family) are not available in php extension, so you have to either provide comments with `-c|--add-comments` command line option, or use a third-party libraries like [vertilia/text](https://github.com/vertilia/text) that provide context-enabled translations and can also handle heredoc/nowdoc strings by keeping your gettext process intact.

Disclaimer: I am a developer of vertilia/text.